# c - can't read pointers from struct using mmap

Tags: c, pointers, struct, malloc, mmap

I'm trying to store a graph on file using  `mmap`  so i read  and write more quickly  but i can't read fields struct fields that are created using malloc (and i can't make them an array)

**the problem is   i can't read back the filed  `map[i].nodes->vertexKey`  from the file

(i think because is because it was created using `malloc`)**

my code is :

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#define COUNT 10
#define FILESIZE (  COUNT * sizeof(struct vertex))
struct node{
    int vertexKey ;
    struct node *nextNode;
};
struct vertex {
    int vertexKey;
    struct node *nodes;
};
int readMmap(){
    const char *filepath = "/tmp/mmapped.bin";
    int fd = open(filepath, O_RDWR  , (mode_t)0600);
    if (fd == -1)
    {
        perror("Error opening file for writing");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    struct stat fileInfo = {0};    
    if (fstat(fd, &fileInfo) == -1)
    {
        perror("Error getting the file size");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (fileInfo.st_size == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: File is empty, nothing to do\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    printf("File size is %ji\n", (intmax_t)fileInfo.st_size);
    struct vertex *map = mmap(0, FILESIZE , PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
    if (map == MAP_FAILED)
    {
        close(fd);
        perror("Error mmapping the file");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    for (off_t i = 0; i < COUNT; i++)
    {
        printf("%d  |", map[i].vertexKey );
        // i can't read map[i].nodes->vertexKey
        printf("%d  \n", map[i].nodes->vertexKey );
        printf("\n" );
    }
    // Don't forget to free the mmapped memory
    if (munmap(map, fileInfo.st_size) == -1)
    {
        close(fd);
        perror("Error un-mmapping the file");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }   
    // Un-mmaping doesn't close the file, so we still need to do that.
    close(fd);
    return 0;
}

int writeMmap(){
    const char *filepath = "/tmp/mmapped.bin";
    int fd = open(filepath, O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, (mode_t)0600);
    if (fd == -1){
        perror("Error opening file for writing");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (lseek(fd, FILESIZE-1, SEEK_SET) == -1){
        close(fd);
        perror("Error calling lseek() to 'stretch' the file");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (write(fd, "", 1) == -1){
        close(fd);
        perror("Error writing last byte of the file");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    struct vertex *map = mmap(0, FILESIZE, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
    if (map == MAP_FAILED)    {
        close(fd);
        perror("Error mmapping the file");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    for (size_t i = 0; i < COUNT; i++){
        struct vertex ss ;
        ss.vertexKey=i;
        struct node *n1 = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        n1->nextNode =NULL ;
        n1->vertexKey=i*10 ;
        ss.nodes = n1 ;
        map[i] = ss;
    }
    // Write it now to disk
    if (msync(map, 100, MS_SYNC) == -1)
    {
        perror("Could not sync the file to disk");
    }
    // Don't forget to free the mmapped memory
    if (munmap(map, 100) == -1)
    {
        close(fd);
        perror("Error un-mmapping the file");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    // Un-mmaping doesn't close the file, so we still need to do that.
    close(fd);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Be specific about the problem you observe.  What result did you expect, and what did you see instead?  Where there any error messages?  Can you reproduce the problem with a smaller example code?

Comment: @JohnBollinger  i edited  the question

Comment: From the question title alone, I speculate that you may be recording in your mmapped file a pointer into a process's private memory.  Such a pointer *value* should transit fine through mmapped memory, but it is not meaningful outside the process whose memory it points into.

Comment: yes i think that's the problem .. my quetion is how can i fix it ... and thank you

Comment: I'd try and get the code working with `read` and `write` before worrying about `mmap`. Learn to walk before you learn to run. You need an on-disk representation of your data that doesn't involve pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How fast does this really need to be?  Using a memory image for your persistent format is a problematic practice -- you need it to be a pretty big win in the larger scheme of things for it to be worthwhile, if it is even possible at all.

If you want a persistent representation of your data, then that representation needs to be self-contained.  Pointers *per se* cannot be supported, but in their place you can use indexes into tables (effectively arrays) of objects.  Better would be if indexing were implicit, but that may not be sufficient for you.  I apologize for being vague, but I'd need to understand the characteristics of your data much better before I could suggest any specifics.

Comment: tank you for your answer : i'm trying to implement a way from storing large graphs  using and Adjacency list : witch mean i need fast access to a specific vertex that's why i tought of mmap

Comment: `mmap()` is for fast, random-access I/O or for shared memory.  Fast, general-purpose, runtime access is better served by regular in-memory data structures.  You seem to be on the I/O track, so what you're after is to *convert* back and forth between external and internal representations.  `mmap()` can help with that, perhaps, but it does not allow you to merge external and internal representations into one.

Comment: if i understand correctly you're saying i can't use mmap here

Comment: I don't know whether you can use `mmap()` for your purposes or not, but the format of the file you are writing via `mmap()` is not viable for serialization / externalization of your graph data.